Best way to improve insulation in basement
My house was built in 1964 (BC Canada). The basement is half "finished", but insulated very poorly. I want to improve the insulation as much as possible as the floor above is freezing cold during the winter, and I want to move my office into the basement. The basement is split into halves that cover the complete footprint of the house. One half is finished, one half is a crawlspace.
In the finished area I am going to remove all the drywall* and use sound insulating rock-wool on the ceiling before installing new drywall. I am also going to replace the windows, and door if I can afford it. The door frame is an odd size and it turns out doors are very expensive.
Questions:

In the unfinished crawlspace area, there is already loosely placed "pink" insulation. Should I replace it with new insulation? Or add more?
The walls are a mix of Uninsulated concrete blocks and 2x2 framing with "yellow insulation". I was thinking I would build new framing over the entire wall and add more insulation to it, including a moisture barrier.
Should I remove the existing "yellow" fiberglass from the existing wall framing? Or just insulate more over top of it?
I'm planning on doing the same (framing + insulation + moisture barrier) on the walls in the crawl space as well, but it's going to be a real PITA due to the uneven flooring. Is there a simpler solution?
The floor is a layer of vinyl asbestos tiles over mastic over the bare foundation concrete. I'm planning on just adding a new layer of flooring insulation and flooring over this. What is the best bang-for-my-buck solution? There are an overwhelming number of flooring/floor-insulation options available online.

Finished area ceiling

Crawl space

Walls


*: Yes I have had it tested for asbestos, I've had a full hazmat survey performed and all hazardous materials already removed. (Except for the tiles. Going to put new floor over them I think.)


This depends if your crawlspace is heated or not. If it is not, you should insulate between the joists and also across them by stapling reflective foil insulation to the underside of the joists. The reflective foil insulation itself creates an r-20 barrier.

Insulate the concrete block walls and add additional insulation to the existing walls.

Consider using rigid mineral wool boards for the crawlspace walls and end joists, anchoring each board to the block using insulation clips (Drill your anchors into the block, impale the insulation onto the anchors and secure with a spring washer)

There are a number of OSB based floor insulation systems. Some use Extruded Polystyrene (EPS) as a base. These should be preferred.


